# Ukkonen algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, suffix-tree

Is there an implementation of the Ukkonen's algorithm for building Suffix Tree in C++?
Any implementation in a high level language is good too.

Comment: What are you interested in doing with it?

Comment: I want to try the problems listed at http://allisons.org/ll/AlgDS/Tree/Suffix/

Comment: I think more work has been done using suffix arrays rather than suffix trees since their memory footprints are smaller.  You can probably find an easier construction algorithm using those.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Mark Nelsons article with source code attached at the end:

http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees/

From the article - *"Both my sample code and the descriptions that follow are based on Ukkonen's work, published in the September 1995 issue of Algorithmica."*

Answer (score 0):

There is somewhat modified Ukkonen's algorithm in my [PATL library](http://code.google.com/p/patl/)